# Reading in unknown integers from a file to create a bitwise table c++

Tags: c++

I am trying to write a program that reads in integers from a file and creates bitwise table. The first line in the file is the numbers of rows (unknown). Each row is two integers (X, Y) that I will use in bitwise operations and print out. Each row will have 6 columns (X, Y, X & Y, X | Y, X ^ Y, ~X). I am stuck at the f for loop to print out the numbers that come from those operations. This is what I have so far:

```
//Variables
  //output of first line of input file is
  //number of rows for problem A
      int N;
      in >> N;

  //output of second to N lines of input file 
      unsigned short X, Y;
      in >> X >> Y;

  //2D array for bitwise table...?
      unsigned short ** bitwiseTable1;
  
  //allocate rows only
      bitwiseTable1 = new unsigned short * [N];

  //allocating the columns
      for (int r = 0; r <= N; r++)
        bitwiseTable1[r] = new unsigned short [6];
 
  //Traverse the array
      for (int r = 0; r <= N; r++)
        for (int c = 0; c < 7; c++)
        {
            //need to read in X,Y from file ? stuck here!
            cout << r << c << r & c << r | c << r ^ c << ~r
        
            cout << X << set(5) << Y << set(6) << (X & Y) 
            << set(6) << (X | Y) << set(5) << (X ^ Y) 
            << set(6) <<  (unsigned short)(~X) << end;
         `enter code here`}
```

some of the code I changed to be able to post this so in is really in file, end is end line, set is set width

Thank you for your help!

Comment: One thing is that an array with size N, uses index 0 to N-1. So your loops run one step too far. Also, I would use a `std::vector` rather than an array of pointers.

Comment: You are mixing things up. ① Read the number of rows. ② Loop that many times. Each time through the loop: ③ read an X, Y pair and ④ write your output row. If you must create a table, it should be filled in, row by row, with each iteration of the loop as well.